# Responsive Testing for AEM Components ( Adobe Experience Manager)

Tags: testing, responsive-design, aem

Hello Gurus / AEM Experts.

I have a situation here and need your advise as to will it add value in performing responsive testing for AEM components.

Currently Our AEM application dev team uses AEM 6.2 for there component development. What I understand from them is they are using Bootstrap and developing the custom components. It could be a Tile , Button , Image , Hero component.

I belong to the testing team and do you see is it necessary to test the responsive design of the components ( using tools like Galen Galen Framework | Automated testing of responsive design )

My understanding is that the out-of- box components created in AEM are already comply to responsive design.  Will that imply to the custom components.

Looking for your valuable inputs based upon which We could devise the next steps.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Will that imply to the custom components.

Short answer: no, unless the devs have made those custom components responsive.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on project requirement. In my current project custom components are responsive and we are doing responsive testing. We have used Galen for the automated testing of look and feel for responsive design.